# Relationship between binary and it's dependency dylib

Tags: mac, command-line

With my understanding, if a binary(ex. rsync) refers(depends on) static library (libxxx.a) and the libxxx.a is updated, a binary have to be re-compiled to reflect libxxx.a's update. Is it correct?

And then, how about if a binary refers(depends on) dynamic library (libxxx.dylib)? Should it be re-compiled too?

The reason why I ask this is that `otool -L rsync` returns old version of libxxhash.0.dylib even though I updated xxhash to 0.8.1 to 0.8.2

```
roushi@roushinoMacBook-Air lib % ls -l libxxhash.*
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  53256 10 28 21:12     libxxhash.0.8.2.dylib
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     21 10 28 21:12 libxxhash.0.dylib -> libxxhash.0.8.2.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 root  wheel  43096 10 28 21:12 libxxhash.a
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel     21 10 28 21:12 libxxhash.dylib -> libxxhash.0.8.2.dylib
roushi@roushinoMacBook-Air lib % file libxxhash.a
libxxhash.a: current ar archive random library
roushi@roushinoMacBook-Air lib % otool -L `which rsync`
/usr/local/bin/rsync:
    /usr/lib/libz.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.11)
    /usr/local/lib/libpopt.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.2.0)
    /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/liblz4.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.9.4)
    /usr/local/lib/libzstd.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.5.5)
    /usr/local/lib/libxxhash.0.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.8.1)
    /usr/local/lib/libcrypto.1.1.dylib (compatibility version 1.1.0, current version 1.1.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1319.100.3)
    /usr/lib/libcharset.1.dylib (compatibility version 2.0.0, current version 2.0.0)
```

As you might be known, I'm not using Homebrew...

Comment: See "Specifying Version Information" in the following article.
 
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/100-Articles/DynamicLibraryDesignGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002013-SW20

Comment: @DavidT I have read the article.  I realized to run `otool -l rsync | grep -3 xxhash`.  This command returned 0.8.1 as current version.  So otool shows library version of client(rsync) compiled time, but library's client (rsync) searches name of libxxhash.0.dylib on runtime and find/uses 0.8.2.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to mind to run `otool` with option `-l`, i.e. `otool -l /usr/local/bin/rsync | grep -3 xxhash`. This command returned the followings:

```
Load command 19
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 64
         name /usr/local/lib/libxxhash.0.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 09:00:02 1970
      current version 0.8.1
compatibility version 0.0.0
```

This result means that `otool` reads `rsync`'s internal info. Not reads dylib's internal info. And also, `rsync` loads dylib by name. Not by dylib version.

`rsync`'s internal info is fixed in compiled time, so it might be shows old version. But **real** dylib being loaded is the latest one.

I did an experiment to prove my above thoughts. That is to move to trash the file named `libxxhash.0.dylib` which is placed in `/usr/local/lib`.

Even though the file is missing, `otool` shows dylib's version. But, `rsync` can't run with `Library not loaded` error.

So, `otool`'s dylib version should not be minded. The depending binary loads the latest dylib. No need to re-compile binary with update of corresponding dylib.